# Can I trigger onChange function when there is an automated value for input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Form.Input`

```
<Form.Input
fluid
required
label="First name"
placeholder="Jose"
name="firstName"
value={ _.isNil(selectedProfile) ? firstName : selectedProfile.first_name }
onChange={this.onCustomerFieldUpdate}
/>
```

as you can see from my code, I am checking if `selectedProfile` is Null or not, if it is null, it will accept the input, but if not, It will get the value for `selectedProfile.first_name`. the problem is, I want to trigger `onCustomerFieldUpdate` even though it gets the value from `selectedProfile.first_name` but it doesn't because it can be triggered `onChange`. is there a way that I can call `onCustomerFieldUpdate` when my value is from `selectedProfile.first_name`?

Comment: If I well understood, you want to factorize a *create* and *update* component for a user profile. What does do `this.onCustomerFieldUpdate` ? If it simply updates the internal state, why don't you fill the initial state with the existing profile (by passing by props if you already have the data from parent, or calling some API method in `componentDidMount`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you checking condition you can call this.onCustomerFieldUpdate from componentDidMount method.